# What would be good alternative function names for "filterHighNumbers"? The word "filter" could go either way

Tags: naming, naming-standards, filtering

The problem I noticed is that I wrote a function called `filterX` which removed any `X` from a list. Then another engineer came along and wrote a `filterY` function which kept only the instances of `Y` in the list. Then it hit me that an "air filter" keeps the "air" while a "noise filter" removes the "noise". So essentially the term "filter" is valid to interpret both ways.

So the alternative names I've come up with, replacing `X` with `HighNumbers` to be concrete:

- `RemoveAllHighNumbers`
- `KeepOnlyHighNumbers`

Are there other better names for such operations?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could use `CullHighNumbers`.

Comment: ["On the troubles of naming and terminology"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology)

Comment: Today this is the kind of question which you ask chatgpt: "give me 100 names for a function that filters/keeps high numbers from a list."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I like `Remove` because it is commonly used in the CLR.
- I don't think you need `All`. It would be pretty weird if the function only operated on *some* of the numbers.
- It is probably obvious (from the argument types) if the function operates on `Numbers`, so you probably don't need that either.
- I find `High` to be a bit ambiguous.

Depending on the context I might use a name like

```
RemoveOutliers()         //If it is clear from the context what that might mean
RemoveIfAbove(int limit) //The argument and the name go together
LimitToAllowedRange()    //If some sort of prevalidation routine
ApplyRangeConstraints()  //If within an algorithm
RemovePeaks()            //If processing audio
```

but filter isn't useless if you combine it with `Out`

```
FilterOutHighNumbers()
```